# Install specific nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, 14.04

I have a problem there, before ubuntu 14.04 I was able to install the old nvidia-319, they work the best with minecraft using shadermod. Now when I type `sudo apt-get install nvidia-319` it installs `nvidia-319`, but after that `nvidia-337`, how can I exclude `nvidia-337` from installation?

[image]

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 6 years.

Answer (score -1):

That is because nvidia-319 is just a dummy transitional package in 14.04:

```
$ apt-cache show nvidia-319
Package: nvidia-319
Priority: optional
Section: restricted/misc
Installed-Size: 36
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: nvidia-graphics-drivers-331
Version: 331.38-0ubuntu7
Depends: nvidia-331
Filename: pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/nvidia-319_331.38-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
Size: 4794
MD5sum: 7779ca67ab9451813094ad89e7aa6ad3
SHA1: 32fd1afe4c1f8e44fe13465ec68b54cf6f82b1a8
SHA256: 9d23ba1a4f9d415ea242b743aeaa14e1d0b9b4bc68d69ec4ee7e675fdbc263a5
Description-en: Transitional package for nvidia-319
 This is a transitional package for nvidia-319, and can be
 safely removed after the installation is complete.
Description-md5: 71184767cf2a112880447ccd8e2ca5fc
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
```

See the 'Depends:' line for that information.

Crazy as it sounds, your best bet could very well be to just use the nvidia-319 package (and its nvidia-dependencies) from saucy. Or, if you feel up for the task, you can try installing the tarball from nvidia's download site.

Comment: But how can I get it install packages from saucy?

Comment: This is a rather dirty solution, but it usually works because the package versions are always higher or equal in trusty than in saucy, however, don't do this too often.

Comment: 1. edit /etc/apt/sources.list, replace 'trusty' with 'saucy';
2. run sudo apt-get update;
3. install the package you need (nvidia-319 or whatever);
4. edit /etc/apt/sources.list again and roll back previous change (replace 'saucy' with 'trusty');
5. run sudo apt-get update again